# Add new instance view controller - IOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have a table view controller called `categoriesController` set in a container.

UPDATED---------------------------------------------------------------------

Categories may or not have subcategories, and number of categories are variable.

In 'categoriesController' view:

Categorie cell with no subcategories (clicked) -> Segue to Articles view

Categorie cell with subcategories (clicked) -> Do not segue. Init new categoriesController with new values (new categories) and reload tableview with new categoriesController instance and new values.

I'm trying to do this because I don't know how many subcategories will be, and I don't want to implement a lot of categories view controller in the storyboard. I want to manage in a only view.

I hope my new explanation is clear for you.

Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do something like:

```
// When the specific cell is selected:
self.categoriesController = [[CategoriesController alloc] init];
```

The old one will be replaced with the new one. This is assuming that you have a property called `categoriesController` which is of type `strong` / `retain`.

Also note that's if you're using ARC. If you're not then you'll want an `autorelease` after the alloc/init of `CategoriesController`.

Comment: This only if he is using ARC, otherwise it is a memory leak. If he's not using ARC: CategoriesController *controller = [[CategoriesController alloc] init]; self.categoriesController = controller; [controller release];

Comment: Hi all, once I got instantiated and set the property, how can I reload the new view controller in the container and dismiss the old one? Many thanks to all.

Comment: @iorf - How are you displaying the VC? Modally? If so, just dismiss it then present the new one.

Comment: Hi Matt, Well in fact I want to set container to new categoriesController instance with new values. Sorry I think my explanation was not accurate.

Comment: What do you mean by container? I think you need to show us some more code.

Comment: I think I understand you now... but why don't you segue to a new categories controller rather than re-initialising the one your in?